# Get Location updates from GPS only, not from Network

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

I need accurate location updates. When using FusedLocationServices from GooglePlayServices, even if I set HighAccuracy, it will get locations from Wi-Fi and cellular when GPS is not available. How do I request locations ONLY from GPS, and with no updates coming in when GPS is not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ...)`

this removed the need for GooglePlayServices.Location completely.